# What's a good camera with IR-Cut for a Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: camera, pi-zero-w

I'm working on an security camera for outside, and want to have vision at night(thus needing Infra-red light, and an infra-red camera), but also don't want that weird pinkish look that an IR camera gives in normal daylight. To solve this, I need an IR-Cut Camera, that can switch between both. I was wondering if you knew any of them that would be worth trying. Most of them have bad reviews with people saying the feature doesn't work at all, or that the Infra-red lights are on all day, wasting power. If you know an alternative instead(that doesn't require buying a special IR-Cut camera), that would be of help too. Thank You!

Comment: Sorry, but Shopping requests are explicitly [off-topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in software, not hardware. I am running a pi zero W with a standard infra-red camera, and have got rid of the pinkish tone with a line in `/boot/config.txt`:

`awb_auto_is_greyworld=1`

This answer I found on [a github thread](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1167%20awb_auto_is_greyworld), supplied by a raspberry pi engineer, so I trust it.